# How do we share proc file of one docker container with another?

Tags: docker, containers, sidecar

I am looking to use one docker container and share the proc file of the container with other containers. Is there a way to achieve that? Or can we leverage linux namespace sharing for that?

I want to run data-dog agent as another container but I don't want to share the proc file of the host to all the container but I only want to share the containers' proc file with the data-dog agent container.

Comment: Can you add a little more context as to why you want to do this? But in theory you could mount the same volume into both containers and copy the proc file into the volume. Assuming you have the right permissions on the volume, it will be available to both containers

Comment: I have added few more details, hope that helps.

Comment: Are you talking about the `/proc` special filesystem?  This is one of the things Docker isolates from other containers and from the host; you can't share it.

Comment: Ohh. So what would be the alternative to following command if I don't want to share the host proc filesystem?

_docker run -d --name dd-agent -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro -v /proc/:/host/proc/:ro_